# Cocos2d stops when I use UIScrollView

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have added one `UIScrollView` in cocos2d. I have 100 records in scrollview.
When I scroll the scrollview, all cocos2d operations, events and schedules stop.

I'm using cocos2d 2.0 for retina support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CCScrollLayer instead of uiscrollview. Cocos2D uses OpenGL ES to render image so its difficult to use UIScrollView. You can find CCScrollLayer in cocos2D extension. Easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

If you want deceleration and bounce you should check out CCKit.

I am my self looking for a way to get the UIScrollView feeling in Cocos2d 2.0 but have not succeeded with solid UIKit and CC2d mixture.

Please report if you do.

Comment: have you had any success with that? all the solutions i found are cocos2d 1.x and dont work with the 2.0 branch.